# Screen configuration in Linux

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

What do the following configurations in Linux [Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) mean?

```
1. caption string "%w"
2. caption always
3. activity "@check %n"
4. defmonitor on
5. vbellwait 0
6. vbell_msg "whoops"
7. vbell off
8. defscrollback 3000
```

And where do I learn or have a screen tutorial?

Comment: I think you mean gnu-screen and not screen (as in a display). You might consider changing the tag of your question to "gnu-screen"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tutorials are easy to find. Have you tried to enter the term "gnu screen tutorial" in a search engine? [Here is one, for a start](http://news.softpedia.com/news/GNU-Screen-Tutorial-44274.shtml).

All of the items on your list are found in the [man pages for screen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen).

```
caption string "%w"
caption always
```

This command controls the display of the window captions. Normally a caption is only used if more than one window is shown on the display (split screen mode). But if the type is set to always screen shows a caption even if only one window is displayed. The default is splitonly.

The second form changes the text used for the caption. You can use all escapes from the "STRING ESCAPES" chapter. Screen uses a default of '%3n %t'.

You can mix both forms by providing a string as an additional argument.

```
activity "@check %n"
```

When any activity occurs in a background window that is being monitored, screen displays a notification in the message line. The notification message can be re-defined by means of the "activity" command. Each occurrence of '%' in message is replaced by the number of the window in which activity has occurred, and each occurrence of '^G' is replaced by the definition for bell in your termcap (usually an audible bell). The default message is

'Activity in window %n'
Note that monitoring is off for all windows by default, but can be altered by use of the "monitor" command (C-a M).

```
defmonitor on
```

Same as the monitor command except that the default setting for new windows is changed. Initial setting is 'off'.

```
vbellwait 0
```

Define a delay in seconds after each display of screen's visual bell message. The default is 1 second.

```
vbell_msg "whoops"
```

Sets the visual bell message. message is printed to the status line if the window receives a bell character (^G), vbell is set to "on", but the terminal does not support a visual bell. The default message is "Wuff, Wuff!!". Without parameter, the current message is shown.

```
vbell off
```

Sets the visual bell setting for this window. Omitting the parameter toggles the setting. If vbell is switched on, but your terminal does not support a visual bell, a 'vbell-message' is displayed in the status line when the bell character (^G) is received. Visual bell support of a terminal is defined by the termcap variable 'vb' (terminfo: 'flash').
Per default, vbell is off, thus the audible bell is used. See also 'bell_msg'.

```
defscrollback 3000
```

Same as the scrollback command except that the default setting for new windows is changed. Initial setting is 100.

Comment: hey, one more question, where can i locate this file - `~/.screenrc` cause i was told to put that configuration in the said file.

Comment: @ruggedbuteducated: That file does not exist by default, you will have to create it yourself. `~` stands for your home directory, so just create the file `.screenrc` in there. Remember that files starting with `.` are hidden by default, so you may not see it in the normal directory listing.

Answer (score 5):

In the usual place:

```
$ man screen
```

The official documentation is usually the first to be read and the best.

Comment: Enter "man screen", then type the "/" character. This will allow you to search. Searching for "caption string", "caption always", etc got me the results you need.